# Changes made in a custom StackLayout (when running) don't appear in the view (Xamarin.Forms)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms, inotifypropertychanged

I have implemented a custom layout whose main characteristic is that the background can be a gradient by giving 2 hex colours. The view itself works perfectly fine, the problem is that changes made in these 2 colours while the program is running do not reflect themselves in the app, the custom Layout receives and changes both new colours and make the gradient correctly, but it doesn't show the changes made. I assume that the problem is that I have not implemented correctly the I INotifyPropertyChanged.

Here is the code of my custom view:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MyProject.Renderers
{
    public class GradientLayout : StackLayout, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public string ColorsList { get; set; }
        public Color[] Colors
        {
            get
            {
                //colorsList have the following format: "HexCode1,HexCode2"
                string[] hex = ColorsList.Split(',');
                Color[] colors = new Color[hex.Length];

                for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
                {
                    colors[i] = Color.FromHex(hex[i].Trim());
                }
                return colors;
            }
        }

//since this is a property that I am not trying to modify, I will not provide the rest of its code to make this as simple as possible.
        public GradientColorStackMode Mode { get; set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

And that is all, if you need more information I will provide it as soon as I see your request, thank to all of you for your time, I hope you have a good day.

**EDIT:** Here you have a class in myProject.ios that is related to the background gradient.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(GradientLayout), typeof(GradientLayoutRenderer))]

namespace MyProject.iOS.Renderers
{
    public class GradientLayoutRenderer : VisualElementRenderer<StackLayout>
    {
        public override void Draw(CGRect rect)
        {
            base.Draw(rect);
            GradientLayout layout = (GradientLayout)Element;

            CGColor[] colors = new CGColor[layout.Colors.Length];

            for (int i = 0, l = colors.Length; i < l; i++)
            {
                colors[i] = layout.Colors[i].ToCGColor();
            }

            var gradientLayer = new CAGradientLayer();

            switch (layout.Mode)
            {
                default:
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToRight:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0.5);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToLeft:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0.5);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0.5);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTop:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 0);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 1);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottom:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 1);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0.5, 0);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTopLeft:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0, 1);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToTopRight:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 1);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 0);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottomLeft:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(1, 1);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0);
                    break;
                case GradientColorStackMode.ToBottomRight:
                    gradientLayer.StartPoint = new CGPoint(0, 0);
                    gradientLayer.EndPoint = new CGPoint(1, 1);
                    break;
            }

            gradientLayer.Frame = rect;
            gradientLayer.Colors = colors;

            NativeView.Layer.InsertSublayer(gradientLayer, 0);
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Also here is the xaml and xaml.cs code related to the declaration and calling of the gradient layout.
XAML.CS:

```
            page.ColorsList = Items[0].StartColor+","+Items[0].EndColor;
            page.Mode = MyProject.Renderers.GradientColorStackMode.ToBottomLeft;
```

XAML:

```
<renderers:GradientLayout
                x:Name="page"
                Opacity="0"
                Mode="ToBottomLeft">
</renders:GradientLayout>
```

**EDIT:** I tried to implement Junior Jiang´s, after I did it I noticed 1 change, the IOS class was executing before the constructor of my xaml.cs class, giving me in `string[] hex = ColorsList.Split(',');` the same error as I previously mentioned because ColorsList had not received any value, so I gave 2 default values to "colors" and implemented a conditional to make sure the constructor code was not executing with ColorsList being null:

```
public GradientLayout()
    {
        if(colorsList != null)
        {
          //colorsList have the following format: "HexCode1,HexCode2"
            string[] hex = ColorsList.Split(',');
            colors = new Color[hex.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
            {
                colors[i] = Color.FromHex(hex[i].Trim());
            }
         // BindingContext = this;
        }
        else
        {
            colors = new Color[2];
            colors[0] = Color.FromHex("#000000");
            colors[1] = Color.FromHex("#000000");
        }
    }
```

After that executing the code did not give any errors, but it was not working as expected since the IOS class only calls the class 1 time (when constructing the view).
I also did not bind anything because I don't understand what I am supposed to do in `//BindingContext = this`

Comment: which property do you modify to change the Colors at runtime?  The setter for that property needs to raise PropertyChanged

Comment: @Jason I modify ColorsList, but is "Colors" the property that access to colorlist and return the colors to the class GradientLayoutRender in my iOS project

Answer (score 1):

I think you should implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` function something like as follow :

```
public class GradientLayout : StackLayout, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Color[] colors;
    public string ColorsList { get; set; }
    public Color[] Colors
    {
        set
        {
            if (colors != value)
            {
                colors = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Colors");
            }
        }
        get
        {
            return colors;
        }
    }

    public GradientLayout()
    {
          //colorsList have the following format: "HexCode1,HexCode2"
            string[] hex = ColorsList.Split(',');
            colors = new Color[hex.Length];

            for (int i = 0; i < hex.Length; i++)
            {
                colors[i] = Color.FromHex(hex[i].Trim());
            }
         // BindingContext = this;
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = "")
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

And better using **Model** to bind properties for Control .Having a look at [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged?view=netframework-4.8) .

==================================Update===================================

You can use Bindable Property to implement that .

Creat a **CustomStackLayout** :

```
public class CustomStackLayout : StackLayout
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty ColorsProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Colors", typeof(string), typeof(CustomStackLayout), "Default Value");

    public string Colors
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(ColorsProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ColorsProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In **Xaml** , adding a Tap method to change property of `CustomStackLayout` :

```
<local:CustomStackLayout HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand"
                         BackgroundColor="Gray">
    <local:CustomStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped"/>
    </local:CustomStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
</local:CustomStackLayout>
```

The `TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped` method :

```
private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine("--TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped--");
    var customStacklayout = sender as CustomStackLayout;
    customStacklayout.Colors = "new value";
}
```

Therefore in **iOS Renderer** file , there is a `OnElementPropertyChanged` method can listen which propery changed . Here you also can update UI .

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(CustomStackLayout),typeof(CustomStackLayoutRenderer))]
namespace AppFrameRenderer.iOS
{
    public class CustomStackLayoutRenderer : ViewRenderer
    {

        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

            var customStack = sender as CustomStackLayout;

            Console.WriteLine("----" + customStack.Colors);

            if (customStack.Colors == "Default Value")
            {
                //--
            }
            else
            {
                BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

The **effect** as follow :

[image]

Comment: It throws an error "Object not set to an instance of an object"

Comment: @JaimeSantos Yeah , because not initializing data for colors . You can modify as follow :`colors = new Color[x];` and you need to set default data for `colors` . I will also update answer .

Comment: Thank you so much for your time, I tried to implement it, I also edited my question to explain what I did since this section was not large enough to answer you, please take a look.

Comment: @JaimeSantos Hi , from edited question , could you share where update data `colors` in project . By the way , `Draw` method only be invoked once time when loading this View .

Comment: @JaimeSantos In addition , you can have a look at [Data Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/xaml-basics/data-binding-basics#data-bindings) . I think here you not used binding , even though modifying model data , the view will not update .

Comment: I don't update Colors or call it from code (except for the IOS class), I update ColorsList. Should I change Draw() then? And if I have to change with what should I substitute it?

Comment: @JaimeSantos I think you shold use Bindable Property to implement it , and monitor the property changed to update UI .https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/bindable-properties